# C# Trimming a string short syntax

Tags: c#

I am reading some code and I am struggling with the short syntax of trimming a short string `readStudentData = line.Split(':')[1].Trim().Split(' ')`. (readStudentData is a string array). Can I get a little bit of explaination(the "[1]" part is the one that loses me)

Comment: It takes the data after the first `:` sign in the original `string`, before the second `:` appearance. Anyway your question is rather off-topic in SO actually

Comment: Break it down into simpler expressions: What does `line.Split(':')` do? Try this: `var x = line.Split(':'); var y = x[1];` When you step through that in the debugger, what do you see happening in the variables?

Comment: But is this a Split overload or it's from the string array?

Comment: @user7431575 Split returns array, so you can use indexer on that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It splits the string on the `:`.  This returns an array.  The `[1]` is an array indexing operation which returns the second item in that array.  It then trims that item, and splits *that* on a space.

Let's consider a basic example.  Say you have the string `line = "title:hi bob "`

```
line.Split(':')                       --> ["title", "hi bob "]
               [1]                    --> "hi bob "
                  .Trim()             --> "hi bob"
                         .Split(' ')  --> ["hi", "bob"]
```

which gets assigned to the `readStudentData` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`Split(':')`

Means that you are you are going to split the `string` into a `string[]` of `Length` = `n chunks` whenever the character has been found. If no character has been found in the string, it will return an array of size 1 containing the entire string.

For instance: `Name:Luis` would return an array of size 2 containing `Name` and `Luis`

`[1]`

Means that you are accessing the second position. In the previous example: `Luis`

`Trim()`

Means that you are removing the leading and trailing whitespace.

and at the end you are performing a similar operation as the beginning, but with  as the character. Again, if no space was found, it will return an array of size `1`

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers:

Trim() removes white spaces and tabs at the beginning and end of a string.